# Sum of Algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $j=e^{\frac{2i\pi}3} $. $j$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q} $ with $X^2+X+1$ as minimal polynomial.
$\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $X^2-2$ as minimal polynomial.

Find the minimal polynomial of $j+\sqrt{2}$.

My solution 
I begin to show that $\mathbb{Q}[j+\sqrt{2}]=\mathbb{Q}[j,\sqrt{2}]$ but I can't.  One subset is evident.

Comment: Let's say that you have the equality of extensions. How do you plan to use it to find minimal polynomial of $j+\sqrt 2$?

Comment: You can always resort to brute force. Let $r=\sqrt{2}$. Powers of $j+r$ are linear combinations of $jr,j,r$ and $1$ over $\mathbb Q$. Since $jr,j,r,1$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, even in the worst case, you only need to find the rank and the null space of a $4\times5$ matrix (which gives you the polynomial $x^4+2x^3-x^2-2x+7$). This may be a bit tedious, but at least it's do-able.

Answer (score 2):

If your task is to find a polynomial for $j+\sqrt2$, it’s not at all hard: Let $f(X)=X^2+X+1$, with $f(\,j)=0$. Consider $f(X-\sqrt2\,)=X^2+(1-\sqrt2\,)X+3-\sqrt2$ and its “conjugate” $f(X+\sqrt2\,)=X^2+(1+\sqrt2\,)X+3+\sqrt2$. Multiply these two $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)$-polynomials, and you get $X^4+2X^3-X^2-2X+7$. You can see that this is a $\Bbb Q$-polynomial having $i+\sqrt2$ as a root. Irreducibility is another question.

Comment: Thanks, it's too simple but I  don't know why it's going well. have you a course, lesson or link about this.

Comment: Well, if you have a separable extension $K\supset k$ and a polynomial $f\in K[X]$, then the product of all the “$k$-conjugates” of $f$ will be a $k$-polynomial. This is essentially the Norm of $f$, from $K[X]$, down to $k[X]$. This is basic Galois theory, but it’s not clear to me from your question that you’ve seen much Galois throey.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general construction to this using the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product):

> If $A, B$ are matrices having eigenvalues $\alpha, \beta$ respectively, then
>   $$ A \otimes I + I \otimes B $$
>   has $\alpha + \beta$ as an eigenvalue.

*Proof.* Suppose $Av = \alpha v$ and $Bw = \beta w$ with $v, w \ne 0$. Then $v \otimes w \ne 0$ and

$$\qquad (A \otimes I + I \otimes B)(v \otimes w) = \alpha v \otimes w + v \otimes \beta w = (\alpha + \beta)(v \otimes w). \qquad\square $$

If we let $\alpha = e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $\beta = \sqrt 2$ then we can take

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

We now have

$$ A \otimes I + I \otimes B =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and after working through the calculations you get
$$ \operatorname{char}(A \otimes I + I \otimes B, t) = t^4 + 2t^3 - t^2 - 2t + 7. $$

Comment: Too hard for me, and don't understand. Maybe in master2 class  Thanks! !

Answer (score 0):

As you observed $\mathbb{Q}[j+\sqrt{2}]\subset \mathbb{Q}[j,\sqrt{2}]$. So the extension $\mathbb{Q}[j+\sqrt{2}]$ can have either degree 2 or 4, but we can exclude the first case since $j+\sqrt{2}$ hasn't the form $a+b\sqrt{d}$, with $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$, and we know all the quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ have the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for a squarefree integer $d$. Hence $\mathbb{Q}[j+\sqrt{2}]=\mathbb{Q}[j,\sqrt{2}]$, so we know the minimal polynomial $p(x)$ has degree 4 and $j+\sqrt{2}$ is a root. But we also know that the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[j]$ send a root of $p(x)$ to another root of $p(x)$, so the roots of $p(x)$ are $j\pm \sqrt{2}$ and $j^2\pm \sqrt{2}$. Hence the minimal polynomial (it follows it actually is the minimal polynomial by degree considerations) is $p(x)=(x-(j+\sqrt{2}))(x-(j-\sqrt{2}))(x-(j^2+\sqrt{2}))(x-(j^2-\sqrt{2}))=x^4+2x^3-x^2-2x+7$

Comment: While your minimal polynomial is correct your argument is skewed. The element $1+\sqrt{2}$ also satisfies no degree $2$ polynomial of the form $x^2-d$ with $d \in \mathbb{Q}$ but $\mathbb{Q}[1+\sqrt{2}]$ still has degree $2$ not $4$.

Comment: In addition, it is not clear (at least most definitely not to a beginner) how the automorphism of the two subfields act on $\mathbb{Q}[j,\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: I made an edit to explain why it can't have degree 2 with more details (it was too sketchy). For  your  second objection probably the user knows it.

Comment: Not for beginner, this is another maths  thanks you.

Comment: @SC30 The steps you need to justify are : $(x-j)(x-j^2)$ is the minimal polynomial of $j$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $x^2-2 = (x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(j)$, $(x-\sqrt{2}-j)(x-\sqrt{2}-j^2)$ is the minimal polynomial of $j$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $(x-j-\sqrt{2})(x-j+\sqrt{2})$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(j)$, **thus** $(x-j-\sqrt{2})(x-j+\sqrt{2})(x-j^2-\sqrt{2})(x-j^2+\sqrt{2})$  is the minimal polynomial of $j+\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a system of linear equations as a last resort. Let $r=\sqrt{2}$. The powers of $x=j+r$ are then linear combinations of $jr,\ j,\ r, 1$ over $\mathbb Q$. In fact, using binomial expansion of $(j+r)^k$ and the identities $j^2+j+1=0,\ r^2=2$, we get
$$
\pmatrix{1\\ x\\ x^2\\ x^3\\ x^4\\ \vdots}
=\underbrace{\pmatrix{0&0&0&1\\ 0&1&1&0\\ 2&-1&0&1\\ -3&6&-1&1\\ 8&-11&4&-8\\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots}}_A\pmatrix{jr\\ j\\ r\\ 1}.
$$
Call the big infinite matrix in the above $A$. We can rewrite any monic polynomial $p(x)=x^k+c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\cdots+c_1x+c_0$ as
$$
p(x)=(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{k-1},1)\ \pmatrix{1\\ x\\ \vdots\\ x^{k-1}\\ x^k}=(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{k-1},1)\ A_{k+1}\ \pmatrix{jr\\ j\\ r\\ 1},
$$
where $A_m$ denotes the submatrix taken from the first $m$ rows of $A$.

Since $jr,j,r,1$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, $p(x)=0$ if and only if $(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{k-1},1)A_{k+1}=0$, meaning that the $(k+1)$-th row of $A$ is a linear combination of the first $k$ rows. So, for $p$ to be the minimal polynomial, $k$ must be the first integer that exhibits such linear dependence.

It is not hard to verify that $A_4$ is invertible but $A_5$ is singular. Therefore, the degree of the minimal polynomial of $x=j+r$ is $k=4$. Solving $(c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3,1)\,A_5=0$, we get $(c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3,1)=(7,-2,-1,2,1)$. Hence the minimal polynomial is $x^4 + 2x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 7$.